# What is the design of libraries like cairo and OpenGL called?

Tags: design, object-oriented, c

I'm not a software engineer, so sorry if the question is elementary. Usually, functions provided by libraries written in C receive a handle from the calling program. This handle directly (if it's a pointer) or indirectly points to an instance of a struct in memory. The calling program can have multiple handles. For example, in an image processing program, it can have different handles representing different images.

I guess that this design (or programming style) has been the precursor to object-oriented programming (OOP) done today with popular languages like Python and C++. But can it be considered OOP itself? If not, what is the technical term for it in the field of software engineering?

Answer (score 1):

I have heard OpenGL described as client-server architecture. You don't have direct access to the actual resources on the GPU similar to how you dont have access to actual resources on a server, just handles.

You can ask the server/GPU to do things but the server might ignore or defer the action related to the actual resource. Resources may become invalidated on the server/GPU and you won't know because all you have is the handle just like files on a server might be removed.